# Limit of an integral where the limit and integral cannot be interchanged

Tags: calculus

Given $r>0$, $a>0$, $\pi/2>\theta>0$, $\pi/2>\theta_0>0$. Evaluate
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\lambda\sin\left(\lambda\log\frac{r}{a}\right)\sinh(\lambda\theta)\,d\lambda}{(\lambda^2+1)\sinh(\lambda\theta_0)}.
\end{equation*}

Needless to say,  the limit and the integral cannot be interchanged. I have tried to evaluate this limit numerically by giving larger and larger values of $r$ in Mathematica, but things become rapidly ill-conditioned.

Comment: May be you can try differentiating the integrand with respect to r. Or you can expand the sin and try integrating, But that applies only if the integral and sum could be interchanged. Have you tried these two methods??

Comment: Assuming $\theta<\theta_0$, the integral is of the form $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(k\lambda)f(\lambda)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda,$$ where $f(\lambda)=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda^2+1}\frac{\sinh(\theta\lambda)}{\sinh(\theta_0\lambda)}$ is integrable on $[0,\infty)$ and $k=\log(r/a) \to \infty$ as $r \to \infty$. Now apply the 
Riemann–Lebesgue lemma. (In fact, this integral can be understood as a Fourier transform of $f(\lambda)$, and since $f(\lambda)$ decays exponentially fast as $\lambda\to\pm\infty$, the Fourier transform will also decay fast.)

Comment: @Lee: Are you saying that the limit is zero if we assume $\theta<\theta_0$?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the logic of taking r to infinity here. The term r is used only within the sin function. No matter how much we increase r here, the sin function will not reach a value greater than 1. In fact, since Sin is a wave function, the sin function will take values ​​in the range of (-1,1). This causes this limit to not converge to a certain value. If you consider $sin(log(\frac{r}{a})) = 1$ (this can be max value of sin), the integral will reach its maximum.